# Run docker from console

Tags: powershell, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, visual-studio-2017

How can I run my docker by docker-compose file? I've created empty ASP.NET Core API project with Docker Support in Visual Studio 2017.

If I run the application from the visual studio I'm having:

```
Hosting environment: Development
Content root path: /app
Now listening on: http://email-receipt:80
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

and then it run a browser and I have my API on http://localhost:32768/my-url

But how can I run in the same way but in PowerShell console?

I  run by: docker-compose up and I also have:

```
Starting mydockercont_mydockercont_1
Attaching to mydockercont_mydockercont_1
mydockercont_1  | Hosting environment: Development
mydockercont_1  | Content root path: /app
mydockercont_1  | Now listening on: http://+:80
mydockercont_1  | Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

But how can I run this app in the browser?

Comment: open the browser and navigate to localhost:80?

Answer (score 1):

You may consider running docker-compose in the background by 
`docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d`.
If you need log you can use
 `docker logs container_name -f`

Answer (score -1):

when you run your docker-compose file in the shell

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up&
```

the & is for reusing your shell window without cancelling the process.

now you can call localhost in your browser. in case you mount your application on port 80:80

in your Dockerfile, only localhost is fine. otherwise use the port your Dockercontainer needs (like  http://localhost:32768).

Comment: instead of `&` better use `-d` since then your shell will not be filled up with log messages while typing new commands in the shell...